# Rename PHP Uploads to a field entry

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to implement a submission system where people can fill out personal information and attach a file upload. Their information should be recorded into a MySQL database and the file should be renamed to one of the fields and then the extension. Here is what I have so far..

This is the form page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Submissions Script DEV</title>
<style type="text/css">
/**** Start page styles ****/

body {
    background: #DFA01B;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    }

#wrap {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background: #fff;
    border: 4px solid #FFD16F;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 20px;
    }
</style>
<body> 
<div id="wrap">
    <div align="center">
    <a href="http://siteurl.com"><img src="logo.png" /> </a>
    <h1 style="font-family:arial">Submissions</h1>
    <p style="font-family:helvetica"> <i> Welcome to the submission page</i> </p> 
</div>
<form method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
              Please enter your first name: <input type="text" name = "fname">
            <p>
              Please enter your last name: <input type="text" name= "lname">
            <p>
              Student #: <input type="text" name= "snumber"/>
            <p>
            Grade: <select name= "grade">
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>11</option>
            <option>12</option>
        </select>
        <p>
<hr>
            <!---Upload file section begins--->
              Please attach your Powerpoint (ppt/pptx/zip) file. The file should be     named student#.zip. (For example; 123456.ppt)
        </p>
        <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1024000">
            <input type="file" name="upload"> 

        <p>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div align="center">
        <input type=button onClick="location.href='instructions.html'" value='Back'>
        <input TYPE="submit" name="upload" title="Send your submission" value="Submit Portfolio"/>
        </div>
      </form>
<p>   
<!---Footer Styling--->
<div style="font-family: Arial;
font-size: 10px;
color: grey;
align: center;">
<!---Footer Contents--->
    <p>Copyright <a href="http://sitename.com">site</a>site</p>
</div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the upload.php:

```
<?php

//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "uploads/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['upload']['name']);

//This gets all the other information from the form
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$upload=($_FILES['upload']['name']);
$snumber=$_POST['snumber'];
$grade=$_POST['grade'];

// Connects to your Database
mysql_connect("localhost", "db_user", "dbuserpass") or die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("sub-data") or die(mysql_error()) ;

//Writes the information to the database
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Submissions` VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$snumber', '$grade',         '$upload')") ;

//Writes the upload to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

//Tells you if its all ok
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been recorded";
}
else {

//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

In the end, I hope to use the snumber field from the form to name the file upload. For example, if someone fills out 12345 in the snumber field and uploads a .zip file, it should automatically be renamed to 12345.zip and stored in the appropriate directory.

How would I go about doing this? I'm very new to PHP but I have done some research pertaining to this problem although I haven't found anything that suits this need.

Comment: Why don't you just update `$target`?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Sorry, really new to all of this.

Comment: It appears you have written some [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities into your application. I suggest learning how to use [PHP's prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), which makes writing database code far safer for you and your users. Also, you have probably written a [Directory traversal vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack), because I don't see any filename sanitizing here. (Perhaps it is in `move_uploaded_file()`?)

Comment: Yes, I am working on proper security next. I needed to get this very basic functionality to work first, now I am working on security additions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update the `$target` variable with the value of the destination file name. For example, change

```
$target = "uploads/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['upload']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $target))
```

to

```
$extension = explode(".", $_FILES['upload']['name']);
$extension = $extension[count($extension)-1];
$target = "uploads/";
$target = $target . $_POST['snumber'] . "." . $extension;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $target))
```

Comment: Perfect! It worked. 

P.S. There is also another question related to this entire system [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509132/need-php-upload-form-to-sort-files-into-sub-directory-based-upon-dropdown). Any input is appreciated for that problem too!